# Add HTML before a specific div?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, the-content

I bought the "Woocommere Checkout Add-Ons" Plugin, which adds upsells to the checkout page - but it only allows to place text after the upsell checkbox.

So I got the idea to add an image with some styled text just above that upsell checkbox, which is wrapped in `<div id="wc_checkout_add_ons">`.

How would I do this? I read about `the_content`but can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like jQuery is best for this case. Mainly answering for myself in case I'll need it again in the future:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#this_comes_before").insertBefore("#wc_checkout_add_ons");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wc_checkout_add_ons">stuff</div>

<div id="this_comes_before">something</div>

</body>
```

**Edit for future me:**

Use this instead you lazy asshole...

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details', 'test99' );
function test99() {
echo "your shit";
}
```